# Vb.net declaration and initialization

Tags: vb.net

Is there any difference between these 2 ways of declaring and initialization ?

```
Dim con as New OracleConnection(connstr)
con=Nothing

Dim con as OracleConnection
con=New OracleConnection(connstr)
con=Nothing
```

Update:
Dim con as OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(connstr)

Is equivalent to ?

Answer (score 1):

They have no differences. But you can still simplify your declaration

```
Using con As New OracleConnection(connstr)
   ' other codes here
End Using
```

The `Using` statement automatically disposes the object after it has been used.

[**SEE also here**](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/differences-declaration-and-instantiation-coding-t1394274.html)

**UPDATE 1**

this one allocates memory directly because of the `NEW` keyword:

```
Dim con as New OracleConnection(connstr)   ' declaration and allocating in the memory
con = Nothing                              ' disposes the object
```

this does not allocate the memory until the `NEW` keyword is supplied.

```
Dim con as OracleConnection          ' declaration only
con = New OracleConnection(connstr)  ' allocates memory
con = Nothing                        ' disposes the object
```

Comment: So i can say for the 1st is compile time memory allocation whereas 2nd is runtime alloc ?

Comment: Based on the answer below option 1 and option are equal actually ?

Comment: as a whole, yes they are the same. But not the same if you call it line by line. The reason is `Dim con as New OracleConnection(connstr)` is not the same with `Dim con as OracleConnection `

Answer (score 1):

VB's `Dim foo As New bar` is syntactic sugar and shorthand for:

```
Dim foo As Bar
foo = New Bar()
```

It's VB's equivalent to C#'s `var` keyword in this sense (except without compiler type inference):

```
var foo = new Bar();
```

Note that you don't need to set local variables to `Nothing` in VB after you're using them as they will automatically be disposed/finalised after they fall out of scope. Preemptively setting variables to `Nothing` is a idomatic habit from VBScript where you needed to nullify COM objects to decrement their Reference-count so they would be disposed, you don't need to do it in VB.NET.